# Google maps polygon zIndex not affecting mouse events

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When I'm painting two polygons with a part of them covering each other, the mouse events are triggred for the polygon that was last painted no matter that it's zIndex is lower!

Is there a way to make mouse event to be triggered for the polygon with higher zIndex?

My code is adding layers of polygons in an asynchronous way (ajax) and  some layers overlap.

I want polygons with higher zIndex's to get the mouse events.

A polygon is created by :

```
function createPolygon(_paths, _strokeColor, _strokeOpacity, _strokeWeight, _fillColor, _fillOpacity, _zindex) {
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: _paths,
      strokeColor: _strokeColor,
      strokeOpacity: _strokeOpacity,
      strokeWeight: _strokeWeight,
      fillColor: _fillColor,
      fillOpacity: _fillOpacity,
      zIndex: _zindex
    });

    return polygon;
  }
```

and afterwards is attached to the map by:

```
for (i in polygonArray) {
      polygonArray[i].setMap(map);
      polygonArray[i].setVisible(true);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you put your code here? so that it will be easy to answer your question...

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I set the panControl property of the map to false which apperantly disables the affect of the zIndex, you must set it to true!